# Not able to add default values to the object in array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to add the fancyItem to the below model. Whenever I try to add the next fancyITem I get below mongo db error:

> MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: natours.fancyitems index: books.name_1 dup key: { : null }\n

To avoid this I am trying to add the default values to the objects so that I don't get this duplicate error.

Kindly suggest better way to handle this issue!

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const fancyItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please enter fancyItem's first name"]
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String
  },
  genre: {
    type: String,
    enum: [
      "guidingLights",
      "luminaries",
      "mavericScientists",
      "menOfLetters",
      "theGrandPhilosophers",
      "architectsOfTheFuture"
    ],
    required: true
  },
  notableWork: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please enter notable work"]
  },
  quotes: [
    {
      quote: {
        type: String,
        default: "There is no quote"
      }
    }
  ],
  books: [
    {
      bookName: {
        type: String,
        sparse: true,
        default: "There is no quote"
      },
      bookURL: {
        type: String,
        sparse: true,
        default: "There is no quote"
      }
    }
  ],
  videos: [
    {
      videoName: {
        type: String,
        maxlength: [
          50,
          "A video description must have less or equal to 50 characters"
        ],
        sparse: true,
        default: "There is no quote"
      },
      videoURL: {
        type: String,
        sparse: true,
        default: "There is no quote"
      }
    }
  ],
  courses: [
    {
      courseName: {
        type: String,
        sparse: true,
        default: "There is no quote"
      },
      courseURL: {
        type: String,
        sparse: true,
        default: "There is no quote"
      },
      platform: {
        type: String,
        sparse: true,
        default: "There is no quote"
      }
    }
  ]
});

const FancyItem = mongoose.model("FancyItem", fancyItemSchema);

module.exports = FancyItem;
```

Comment: Could you also paste the definition of `books.name_1` index ?

Comment: Mickl Thanks for your time..The bug was in the book.name_1 field. I had changed the model definition from unique true to false but had not dropped the index..Hence the issue..Fixed it referring to other answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error you have provided says that there's already a record with null as the name. In other words, you already have a book without a name.

The relevant documentation for this:

> If a document does not have a value for the indexed field in a unique
>   index, the index will store a null value for this document. Because of
>   the unique constraint, MongoDB will only permit one document that
>   lacks the indexed field. If there is more than one document without a
>   value for the indexed field or is missing the indexed field, the index
>   build will fail with a duplicate key error.
>
> You can combine the unique constraint with the sparse index to filter
>   these null values from the unique index and avoid the error.

[Unique Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/#unique-index-and-missing-field)

> Sparse indexes only contain entries for documents that have the
>   indexed field, even if the index field contains a null value.

[Sparse Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/)

Comment: Hi Mian..Thank you for your time..Bug was with the older index fornthe field..I dropped the older index and application works smoothly now..